# How to pick a trekking/hiking shoelaces?

Tags: boots, shoelaces

The laces of my [Scarpa MAIN boot](http://www.trek1.co.il/product/%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94-main-%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/) been worn and torn after a few years. Since the boots are still in very good shape, I'm looking for a new lace.

What features should I be looking for in trekking/hiking lace?

Comment: I like a good titanium-kevlar blend, with a waterproof coating.

Comment: @BenCrowell, have you considered [Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium), ha ha

Answer (score 4):

From my personal experience, this is what I can tell:

- Using a flat/softer material lace is better. This allows for the lace to hold on the knots.
- I have laces made of harder material (Nylon types). The knots on these tend to come off when they get wet. Mostly because they don't grip each other.
- Avoid laces which are cylindrical, they do not hold knots well.
- Always buy laces of good length. Do not buy short ones. Sometimes these laces can be used to tie up something (I have used them to make makeshift clothes line within my tent). The trade off with longer laces is that you need to tie them up properly. There's always a chance of the loops getting stuck and you tripping if the loops are too big. (Has happened to me multiple times)

Note: I had tried to tie the laces around my ankles to reduce the free length after the knot. This isn't much comfortable for me. I know many who tie up around their ankles though.

Comment: Dont tie your laces around ankles folks. It decreases your range. When you are in full stride, your ankle should be forward while the back of the boot is back. By tying them around the back, it restricts the motion of your ankles, and if you can’t bend your ankles, you can’t bend your knees. Destroys/Accelerates the breakdown of your boots.

Comment: @AM_Hawk Yup. My problem was the same one. I did try it once or twice and the way the lace holds tight on your ankle put me off.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the best shoelaces are the wide, flat and fairly soft ones - no special plastic coating, just canvas. They stay together the best and can take a lot of punishment. Accidental strong knots are also easier to undo, since it is easier to get a finger behind an edge due to its flatness.

The ones on the picture here seem a bit too shiny, so perhaps they are coated with some layer. This is the general style I recommend, though.

http://shoelacestring.com/shop/images/categories/Extra_Super_Wide_Shoelaces_Shoestrings.jpg

Comment: I don't do much hiking so I refrained from answering myself, but I also like flat laces; they seem to be easier on the fingers and as you stated easier to un-knot. (+1)